# Pyparsing - Simple parsing from numbers into a list

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to make a simple parser but I alway get an Exception (`pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(ABCD...), found '6'  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)`.

For example: If i have this data (in a .txt):

```
Mo:6,8,9
Di:7,5,2
Mi:5,2,6
Do:2,5,6,7
Fr:2,5,7
#
Mo:5,4,8
Di:1,5,6,7
Mi:5,2,1
Do:2,5
Fr:4
```

I want to get this back:

```
[
    {
        "mo": [6, 8, 9],
        "di": [7, 5, 2]
        #...
    },
    {
        "mo": [5, 4, 8],
        "di": [1, 5, 6, 7],
        #...
    }
]
```

Here's my code:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
import re

result = []

with open("days.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
    splitted = content.split("#")

    for split in splitted:
        tmp = {}
        for day in split.split("\n"):
            if day is "" or day is "\n":
                continue
            text_format = Word(alphas) + ":" + Word(alphas)

            parsed_split = text_format.parseString(day)

            weekday = parsed_split[0]
            numbers = re.sub("\s+", "", parsed_split[-1]).split(",")

            tmp[weekday] = numbers

        result.append(tmp)
```

I want to parse numbers from the dates into a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

6does not fit to `alphas` use `alphanums` or `nums` instead.

```
text_format = Word(alphas) + ":" + Word(alphanums)
```

Reference: [Common string and token constants](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#common-string-and-token-constants)

Comment: Also, check out `pyparsing_common.integer` for parsing integers, and `delimitedList` for parsing lists of entries delimited by commas (make the parser do all the comma splitting work, so you don't have to)